# What is the fragment lifecycle when a bottom sheet is opened and closed in the fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottom-sheet

I am setting a few flags in the following lifecycle functions of the fragment:

- `onCreate`
- `onStart`
- `onResume`

And I am clearing the flags in the following functions:

- `onStop`

However, if I open a bottom sheet and then close it, the flags are cleared and not set again. Hence, I want to understand the fragment lifecycle when a modal bottom sheet is opened and closed.

Comment: Did you call bottom sheet show right? If you call show I think no lifecycle callback of fragment is call. It means onStop not call too

Comment: @CôngHải I am navigating to the fragment from the bottom sheet again instead of dismissing. But i guess onCreate should be called again in that case ?

Comment: Could you attach your code when you navigate instead of dismiss